# Output of a command going in background on Mac

Tags: osx, job-control

I have an issue on my Mac.

```
HQSML-1584960:puppet rmoham860$ git diff
[2]+  Stopped                 git diff

HQSML-1584960:puppet rmoham860$ jobs -l
[1]- 37022 Stopped (tty output): 22git diff
[2]+ 38314 Stopped (tty output): 22git diff
HQSML-1584960:puppet rmoham860$
```

I want to see the output on my screen instead of sending it to the background jobs.

Something like this

```
HQSML-1584960:puppet rmoham003c$ git pull
Already up to date.
HQSML-1584960:puppet rmoham003c$ git diff
HQSML-1584960:puppet rmoham003c$
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

It sounds like you either have:

- An alias or function for `git` within your shell.
- You've introduced some alias within `git` itself through its `~/.gitconfig` file, in the `[aliases]` or `[include]` sections of that file.
- You've introduced an executable file named `git` to your `$PATH`.

#### 1. Alias/Function

To check on the alias/function, you can run this command to see if there's one:

```
$ type -a git
git is /usr/local/bin/git
git is /usr/bin/git
```

If you see something besides these, that may be what's causing your issue.

#### 2. ~/.gitconfig

If it doesn't appear to be an alias/function within your shell, then take a look at your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
...
...
 [include]
     ### https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/master/gitalias.txt
     path = ~/.gitalias_slm.txt

 [alias]
     # one-line log
     l = log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h\\ %ad%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --decorate --date=short

     a = add
     ap = add -p
     c = commit --verbose
     ca = commit -a --verbose
     cm = commit -m
     cam = commit -a -m
     m = commit --amend --verbose
...
...
```

#### 3. `$PATH`

If it's neither of the above, then check to see if you have `git` on your `$PATH`. Here I've added a `git` file to `~/bin` which is on my `$PATH`.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/smingolelli/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

This is the `git` file:

```
$ cat ~/bin/git
#!/bin/bash

echo 'hi'

$ ll ~/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x 1 smingolelli staff 23 Apr 10 08:14 /Users/smingolelli/bin/git
```

Now when I run `git` I'm actually running my script in `~/bin` not the actual `git` executable.

```
$ git
hi
```